# PDF not shown correctly

Tags: objective-c, swift, pdfview

In my app I use a window with a single PDF view for showing some information. When the window is shown first the display is fine:

[image]

But when showing it once again the PDF inside is shifted:

[image]

The code for opening the window is this:

```
- (IBAction)viewClicked:(id)sender {
  NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"my.pdf"];
  pdf = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];
  [_pdfWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
  _pdfView.document = pdf;
}
```

This is called right after the app starts. The window is closed with the red close button. Right after that the above `viewClicked` is repeated and shows the shifted picture.

The same happens in Swift:

```
@IBAction func viewClicked(_ sender: Any) {
  let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:"my.pdf")
  pdf = PDFDocument(data:data as! Data)
  pdfWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
  pdfView.document = pdf
}
```

**Edit** One further observation: cursor right, which is propagated to the PDFView directly, when issued from the wrong display results in this:

[image]

which is only the 2nd page of the PDF.

**Edit2** If anyone is interested, I attach the ObjC/Swift XCode projects. You just need to adapt the PDF file location in AppDelegate. [Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66691423/Archiv.zip)

Comment: PDFKit in 10.12 is buggy. Unrelated tip: use `[[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:myURL]`.

Comment: @Willeke Didn't make a difference :-(

Comment: Apple really screwed up PDFKit in 10.12. Try the 10.12.2 update that was just released, it seems to fix at least few PDFView issues, maybe it fixes yours as well.

Comment: @danielv I feared that. The update hasn't arrived Germany yet, but I'll try as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: @danielv The update just arrived. It did not change anything.

Comment: Not necessary related but why do you need to reload the doc each time you view the window? Hard to tell what the problem is without debugging it, PDFView is SO messy. Few things to check/try: 1. Xcode includes a visual view hierarchy debugger, check which of the views are actually "off" (PDFView consists of many internal sub views). 2. What's your PDFView's `PDFDisplayMode`? Try resetting it after opening the window. 3. Try calling PDFView's `layoutDocumentView()` 4. Check your constraints.

Comment: @danielv I have attached my project (see Edit2). This is just a quick demo hack to show the issue. Without reloading it's fine. But the reload is part of the issue. It's not always the same file I show and after reloading a different file I get the same issue. I also submitted a bug report. PS. The layoutDocumentView did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, PDFView is annoying like that. set the PDFView's document to nil before assigning it a new document:

```
_pdfView.document = nil;
_pdfView.document = pdf;
```

This will reset it and solve your problem.

Also, you don't need to set needsDisplay on the window's view.

Comment: Wow! The needsDisplay was one of those straws I tried :-) Thanks a bunch! That'll give you a bounty (in 21 hours when possible)

Comment: PDFKit is *really* buggy. Just found another issue with paging (right to end and left to beginning) where it ends up with "something" but not the beginning. Thumbs down, Apple.

Comment: It's with multi-page PDFs with more than 4 pages. Right/Left shows only the 2nd page instead of 1&2. If Apple happens to read this comment when dealing with my bug report, do what you think you need to do (as you always will). I'll make a work around :P

Comment: FWIW: I ended up using a page counter and when reaching page 1 just to issue `_pdfView.document = NULL; _pdfView.document = pdf.copy;`. Note the `copy` as it seems that the view clobbers the original document.